# How to find the closest event element

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery. I want to find the closest class `.hidebox` to the element that created the event. I tried to use `parent`, `find` and `closest` but they all refer to the level my element located. I'm just looking to the closest `.hidebox` class I can find to my event element.

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" class="hideBox-tab " >show div</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<div class="hideBox" ></div>

<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" class="hideBox-tab " >show div</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
</td>
    <div class="hideBox" ></div>
</td>
</tr>
```

```js
$(".hideBox-tab").click(function(){
    $(this)
        .parent().parent()
        .find(".hideBox")
        .toggle();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Please add your HTML to the question. We can't tell you how to traverse the DOM without seeing it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The issue is because your HTML is invalid - you can't have `div` elements nested directly inside a `table`. They need to be within a `td` or `th`.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Rory McCrossan; your first `hideBox` present directly in `<table>` tag which is invalid; and 2nd `hideBox`'s `<td>` present outside of `<tr>` which is also invalid. So I am using below HTML which is somewhat different from yours but I believe you want that only

**HTML:**

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" class="hideBox-tab " >show div</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="hideBox" ></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" class="hideBox-tab " >show div</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="hideBox" ></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**JQuery code:**

```
$(".hideBox-tab").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("tr").find(".hideBox").toggle();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite of your html validity you can try do it like this:

```js
$(".hideBox-tab").click(function(){
    $(this)
        .closest("tr")
        .next("tr")
      .find(".hideBox")
        .toggle();
    return false;
});
```

```css
.hideBox {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="hideBox-tab">show div</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="hideBox">aaa</div>      
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="hideBox-tab">show div</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="hideBox">bbb</div>      
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```