# How to find the closest event element2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I opened post where i asked for assistance with jquery code:
[How to find the closest event element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34155224/how-to-find-the-closest-event-element)

unfortunately, other user didn't read my issue.

I have A link. clicking on it will show/toggle div. my problem is that my div is not always located at the same level from the A link. sometimes the A link is 1 level upon the hide DIV. sometime it's 2 levels or more. sometime it's below it

how can I find the closest DIV, that contain the class ".hidebox", to the A link?

```
 <a href="#" class="hideBox-tab " >show div</a>

$(".hideBox-tab").click(function(){
    $(this)
        .parent().parent()
        .find(".hideBox")
        .toggle();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: why "possible"? @ColBeseder

Comment: Can you post html examples?

Comment: @RenanAraújo. no. because each time it's look different...

Comment: @Roi: in which case try and put together a snippet of HTML that is generally applicable to your problem. Without *seeing* the HTML we can't advise you on traversing it. Perhaps if you show the two extremes, one in which it's the 'furthest' away and another in which it's as 'near' as it can be. Otherwise you'll need to normalise your HTML structure in some way.

Comment: Asking the same question a second time is sure to get one of them closed.  If the answer on the other question doesn't help you the problem might be how you're asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you and an `<a>` to show/toggle the `div` the `<a>` must be outside the `div`:

```
<a href="#" class="hideBox-tab">toggle and show div</a>
<div class="hideBox">
  Content here  
</div>
```

Then you need to find in your HTML one tag that allways englobes `a.hideBox-tab` and `div.hideBox`.
For example: `div.partial-content`:

```
<div class="partial-content">
  <a href="#" class="hideBox-tab">toggle and show div</a>
  <div class="hideBox">
    Content here  
  </div>
</div>
```

And your JS will be like this:

```
$(".hideBox-tab").click(function(){
    $(this).closest(".partial-content").find(".hideBox").toggle();
});
```

I created a snippet, take a look at it:

```js
$(".hideBox-tab").click(function(){
    $(this).closest(".partial-content").find(".hideBox").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="partial-content">
  <a href="#" class="hideBox-tab">toggle and show div</a>
  <div class="hideBox">
    Content here  
  </div>
</div>

<div class="partial-content">
  <a href="#" class="hideBox-tab">toggle and show div</a>
  <div>
    <div class="hideBox">
      Content 2 here  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This solution works for one or more levels between `a.hideBox-tab` and `div.hideBox`.

Comment: thanks, by not working. clicking on the A link doesn't show the DIV. how can i show it to you?

Comment: I created a snippet too. Take a look at my updated answer